# MongoDB Aggregation: How to add a nested field that is the sum of a double nested field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have multiple documents of the following structure.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60c07a1f9853c900c2026440"),
  "ProductID": "A",
  "Colours": [
    {
      "ID": "01",
      "Name": "BLACK",
      "Sizes": [
        {
          "Code": "S1",
          "Stock": 2
        },
        {
          "Code": "S2",
          "Stock": 3
        }
      ] 
    },
    {
      "ID": "02",
      "Name": "WHITE",
      "Sizes": [
        {
          "Code": "S1",
          "Stock": 5
        },
        {
          "Code": "S2",
          "Stock": 2
        }
      ] 
    }  
  ]
}
```

I want to retrieve the documents with an additional field inside each element of `Colours` called `TotalStock` that contains the sum of `Stock` from all `Sizes` inside while leaving out the `Sizes` themselves.

So my retreived document would look like this:

```
{
  "ProductID": "A",
  "Colours": [
    {
      "ID": "01",
      "Name": "BLACK",
      "TotalStock":5
    },
    {
      "ID": "02",
      "Name": "WHITE",
      "TotalStock":7
    }  
  ]
}
```

I was able to somewhat achieve this with a combination of `$unwind`, `$addFields`, `$sum` and `$project`. This is my query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Colours"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Colours.TotalStock": {
        "$sum": "$Colours.Sizes.Stock"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "ProductID": 1,
      "Colours.ID": 1,
      "Colours.Name": 1,
      "Colours.TotalStock": 1,
    }
  }
])
```

**The Problem**

My query gives me a separate document for each colour because of `$unwind` whereas I need them in the same document. I'm still learning and don't know how to and if I should use `$group` for this. What do I need to change in my query to get the expected result?

[Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8e7Y74fYsRF)'s a playground with the above example and query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$unwind` `$group` etc work on collection level, and also destroy the document structure you dont need them if all the info you need are inside 1 document. (but sometimes they are simpler to use).

Instead you can use `$map`,`$filter`,`$reduce` and do things on document level without changing the document structure.

```json
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Colours": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Colours",
          "as": "color",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$color",
              {
                "TotalStock": {
                  "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$$color.Sizes",
                    "initialValue": 0,
                    "in": {
                      "$let": {
                        "vars": {
                          "total_stock": "$$value",
                          "csize": "$$this"
                        },
                        "in": {
                          "$add": [
                            "$$total_stock",
                            "$$csize.Stock"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nkpd8usNpLG)

Query doesn't change the documents, only adds ones extra field called `$TotalStock`

Comment: Pretty neat! Perfect example to learn the use of `$let`, `$reduce` and `$mergeObjects`. In `$reduce` I see that we can just use `$add` without using `$let`, is there a downside to doing it that way or did you use `$let` to make it easier to understand what was happening?

Comment: i think you mean the extra `$let` to give names to `$$value` and `$$this`, we dont need it, its just names to help undestand the code easier.MongoDB for now is slow allocating memory for new variables with `$let` so if perfomance is important remove it.I think they will fix it in the future,